# Will Stack Overflow disallow the GPT web crawler?

Tags: discussion, chatgpt, scraping

I do not know if Stack Overflow allows the ChatGPT Web Crawler to scrape information from this site so that it can use it to train its large language model, but OpenAI are reportedly encouraging sites to [disallow the GPT web crawler](https://platform.openai.com/docs/gptbot) if they are concerned about their information being used to train the bot.

Since the crawler could be scraping information available on Stack Overflow to train the bot, will Stack Overflow disallow the crawler or is it already disallowed?

Comment: Isn't it Open AI themselves who should be concerned about getting their bot trained on content potentially generated by itself? If you don't want your dog to get ill because the neighbors feed it chocolate, then maybe not let it roam freely on the neighbors lawn?

Comment: Anyway, the content on SO is licensed in such a way that it cannot be reused without attribution given. If Open AI is doing that, then I believe they are violating the licensing terms.

Comment: @Lundin, which would justify a ban on the web cralwer if there is evidence that it scrapes as it's responses do not attribute the source.

Comment: @Lundin Does the license block that though? Because if we see learning as a form of adaptation, then I have yet to see a software project that lists all the SO posts they ever used for knowledge. And that is basically what OpenAI does. It does not copy. It learns.

Comment: "*block the GPT web crawler's IP address*" - really? Haven't they heard about [robots.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt)?

Comment: Ban is a strong word. I think what you mean is "politely ask it not to crawl" by disallowing in robots.txt...

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer same difference

Comment: @Lundin I don't think Qing is suggesting this because they're concerned about the quality of training data.

Comment: @Bergi Did you not read the second paragraph of the information you linked to? *Not all robots comply with the standard; [...] may even start with the portions of the website where they have been told to stay out.*

Comment: @AndrewMorton More important quote from the WP article: "*This relies on voluntary compliance*". My comment was in response to OpenAI **themselves** "*reportedly encouraging sites to block […]*". I'm not sure where Quing Guo got these reports from, but the answer below shows that [OpenAI actually know](https://platform.openai.com/docs/gptbot) how to achieve this properly in accordance with the relevant web standards.

Comment: @J.Vergeer "It does not copy. It learns." Very good question about the difference of copying and learning. Although with the CC license an adaptation must still be under the same license. Learning itself must be something completely different. Maybe one could even invent a version of the CC license that only allows learning from it for humans? Some kind of discrimination. Anyway, these legal problems should be sorted out one way or another.

Comment: Disallowing in robots.txt and potentially blocking the [IP ranges](https://openai.com/gptbot-ranges.txt) hardly matters if OpenAI gets its hands on the data dumps.

Comment: Open AI have a 150000$ lawsuit to answer to for violating the copyright act of the content it uses to train it's not. Stack Overflow should also follow suit.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**Yes, Stack Overflow has blocked OpenAI's web crawler, GPTBot from crawling the sites.**

The [`robots.txt`](https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt) file contains the following lines:

```
User-agent: GPTBot
Disallow: /
```

which is the suggested way from [the official documentation about GPTBot](https://platform.openai.com/docs/gptbot).

However, as [The Verge](https://www.theverge.com/2023/8/7/23823046/openai-data-scrape-block-ai) stated,

> It does not retroactively remove content previously scraped from a site from ChatGPT’s training data.

Comment: Not sure if that is enough. This link speaks of ChatGPT-User instead of GPTBot: https://platform.openai.com/docs/plugins/bot

Comment: With the number of scraper sites out there, this probably won't be terribly effective.

Comment: ChatGPT-User is specifically for plugins. I assume both have to be blocked

Comment: @Laurel Wouldn't matter anyway; there's a large amount of scrapers that do not respect robots.txt. They'd need server-sided user-agent blocks, and that assumes the scraper sets a special user agent. Blocking the AI scrapers efficiently is a nightmare

Comment: True but ChatGPT *should* respect it. But let's face it, the bot has already scraped a good amount of data from the site because that's why it can guestimate smartly worded nonsense to programming questions. I can't imagine adding a block to a robots.txt file is going to make it forget all that prior training. The only reason to block anything at this point is to help reduce server costs, not to prevent data from going out there.

Comment: Well that's a shame. I wonder why do this, besides "we insist on credit all of a sudden". It's handicapping the most useful programming assistant to ever exist.

Comment: I learn things when browsing the web or SO, and when I'm asked to solve a problem, I don't have to append it with "I learned this from Khan Academy" - I just have the knowledge and that's it. A non-trivial case is copy-pasting significant work - which I've never seen ChatGPT do - then, well, you put your stuff out on a public forum, good luck enforcing even if you wanted to (exceptions apply).

Comment: ChatGPT is not at all "the most useful programming assistant to ever exist". I have worked with people who have leaned on it heavily, and it just produces absolute garbage. Semi-functional garbage, but garbage all the same. Especially as, unlike a human who will adapt an answer from SO to fit into the larger picture, ChatGPT provides an answer based on the prompt. Projects which use ChatGPT often end up being unmaintainable Franken-code.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon The most useful programming assistants are docs, along with human-written knowledge repository sites like Stack Overflow. ChatGPT just regurgitates completions based on scrapes of pre-existing data, with a good deal of hallucinations on top. Most answers GPT gives you can be acquired more reliably by going to the source, and it fails terribly on anything non-trivial in my experience.

Comment: @LukeStevenson, it stands to reason if ChatGPT is producing semi-functional garbage then better data would make it at least produce slightly better garbage. Why cut it off from the best source of programming related answers on the internet? Is the goal to punish people who (over) use it by making them produce even worse code? I just can't see the reasoning behind "someone is using the wrong tool, so I hate that tool, so let's try to make that tool worse".

Comment: Shouldn't "has blocked OpenAI's web crawler, GPTBot from crawling the sites" be "has attempted to indicate to OpenAI's web crawler, GPTBot, that it would prefer that it didn't crawl the sites"?

Comment: No, that does not stand to reason, @yeerk.  The reason ChatGPT produces poor code is that it has no understanding of the semantics of the code it produces or of the context it is to be used in, or of the nuances that sometimes guide which approaches are best in a given situation.  More data is not going to help ChatGPT in those areas.

Comment: @LukeStevenson Barring from SO won't help GPT5 with the garbage.

Comment: @JohnBollinger like it or not, Transformers style AI is improved with additional data. Some of the biggest complaints of this style of AI is actually that it plagiarizes (ex, stable diffusion stealing art styles). There isn't really a question about this, it simply is the way it is. Now, it is more debatable whether or not this will help the AI in the specific area you mentioned. I recommend reading about "Attention" (a machine learning term). AI that use this DO, in some sense, "understand" nuances, perhaps only in a statistical sense, but they definitely do react to specific input.

Comment: @yeerk Most people here know how a Transformer works and what the Attention mechanism is. It's really nothing esoteric. But you are basing your argument on a word, the fact that it's called "attention" because it weights specific inputs more than others doesn't mean the network is "attentive" like humans are. You should not attribute anthropomorphic traits to a statistical model. ChatGPT has no practical experience. Having said so, SO is not meant to teach programming so it's unlikely that **any** intelligence could use it to learn programming regardless of the number of parameters they have.

Comment: I just asked GPT 4 a Typescript question and it returned Python. I haven't felt like this since road rage in traffic. I need to go walk it off now.

Comment: @suchislife i mean, what'd you expect

Comment: Something has happened to it lately... It reminds of when I took the 2nd COVID shot and couldn't form meaningful thoughts for about a week. It appears to be... less logically intelligent and more concerned with how I feel, waaay more English and sometimes no code on a coding question.

Comment: @MargaretBloom, that seems disingenuous. I never mentioned teaching ChatGPT to program, nor would I want to. I just prefer for my code completion in Copilot (different from ChatGPT, but similar) to be trained on good input data.

I would generally recommend people don't use ChatGPT to code, but I would prefer to say "you should know what every line you write does" and not "I'm actively tried to make ChatGPT worse by limiting the data is has access to".

Comment: @yeerk Copilots are similar but different enough, specifically trained to produce code. You cannot just say that ChatGPT is a great coding tool when you actually meant one of the copilots.

Comment: (*[Stable Diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_Diffusion)*. *[GitHub Copilot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub_Copilot)*)

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава, to be fair I said "if ChatGPT is producing semi-functional garbage", which is a bit different than "a great coding tool". But point taken, they were trained with different datasets.

Comment: If Stack Overflow disappears because of ChatGPT, where will ChatGPT collect its training data? Someone says ChatGPT is better than Stack Overflow, that's not a important thing. Eeven that better ChatGPT is trained from data created by humans.